# Convert array to object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd like to convert an array into an object using one of the properties as key.

For instance:

```
var stations = [ { name: 'A Coruna', ds100: 'OECSC' }, ... ];
```

I'd like to get `stationByDs100`:

```
{ 'OECSC': { name: 'A Coruna', ds100: 'OECSC' }, ... }
```

At the moment I do it as follows:

```
var stationByDs100 = {};
stations.forEach(station => stationByDs100[station.ds100] = station);
```

I'm looking for a better way to accomplish this - is it possible with a one-liner without explicit variable declaration?

For instance in Java 8 this could have accomplished with streams and collectors in one line like:

```
Map<String, Station> stationByDs100 = stations.stream()
    .collect(toMap(Station::getDs100, identity()));
```

So I was thinking maybe there's a similar way in JS.

I'm using Node.js so OK to use the latest JS/ES features Node.js supports.

I've browsed through a rougly dozen existing answers but they mostly use older JS/ES versions and suggest even longer solutions.

Comment: Use [*Array.prototype.reduce*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-array.prototype.reduce), see [*MDN*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) for examples.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek One-liner, without explicit variable declaration, from said criteria it is better.

Comment: Is there a specific purpose for wanting the code to be a one-liner?
Usually one-line code, especially involving functional-style array methods, are slower than the equivalent code using for/while loops and more than one line of code

Comment: @Zorgatone No technical reason. I don't care about performance in this case and wanted to learn more about functional style in JS as I'm quite weak in that.

Comment: Ok, makes sense

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names).

```js
var stations = [ { name: 'A Coruna', ds100: 'OECSC' }],
    object = stations.reduce((o, a) => Object.assign(o, { [a.ds100]: a }), {});

console.log(object);
```

Comment: I would prefer `Object.assign({}, o, { [a.ds100]: a })` instead of `Object.assign(o, { [a.ds100]: a })` to prevent side effects. just a personally preference.

Comment: the difference is, i return the same object, while NonPolynomial suggest to use a new object all time.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, I got it, thank you. I think it's not really necessary in this case as accumulator object is only used in reduction.